Which approach is cheaper when iterating through a vector to sort it based on a list of strings?
I am writing the elements of a throwaway vector to a file in the order provided by a list of strings.
Given
std::vector<std::string> data {
    "jpg  yuvj420p 1080x2400 1:1   9:20",
    "jpeg yuvj420p 1536x2048 72:72 3:4",
    "jpg  yuvj444p 1920x1080 1:1   16:9",
    "png  rgba     150x150   NA    NA",
 /* ... up to 35 (56?) more, all of which start *
  *     with one of the strings in extensions   */
};
std::vector<std::string> extensions {
    "png", "jpg", "jpeg", // ... 2 to 4 more
};
std::ofstream file ("data.txt");

Straightforward approach:
for (auto& ext : extensions)
{
    for (auto& it : data)
        if (it.starts_with(ext))
            file << it << '\n';
}

Using std::erase_if:
for (auto& ext : extensions)
{
    std::erase_if(
        data,
        [&ext](std::string& it) {
            if (it.starts_with(ext)) {
                file << it << '\n';
                return true;
            } else return false;
        }
    );
}

Result:
// data.txt
png  rgba     150x150   NA    NA
... // more lines starting with 'png'
jpg  yuvj420p 1080x2400 1:1   9:20
jpg  yuvj444p 1920x1080 1:1   16:9
... // more lines starting with 'jpg'
jpeg yuvj420p 1536x2048 72:72 3:4
...

The idea behind the second approach is to avoid iterating over the elements of data which have already been written to file on all subsequent outer loop executions. However, is that worth the overhead due to the call to std::erase_if (with data.size() - number_of_previous_matches applications of the predicate (the lambda), some move operations, and extensions.size() calls to data.erase)?

"sort elements of a vector based on a match against a list of predicates" - Do you really mean sort? It looks like you mean erase.

how many predicates and vectors are there ? 2 or 1,000,000 ? the answer may vary

These are not equivalent. In the first snippet any item may be output multiple times. In the second they can't. Also, I don't see in what sense this is "sorting". It seems like "filtering" or "matching". Sorting would imply that each item appears again once in the output. But here an item might not appear at all or appear multiple times (in the first snippet).

@Ted Lyngmo - Yes, I meant sort. vec not being needed after file.close(), I thought I'd shorten the iterations through vec for every subsequent loop through preds.

@Erendil Where is the sorting in your example? Why are you erasing when you want to sort?

Why should string_view be better than a string& if the input is a string? Doesn't make much sense.

As far as sorting goes: Sort the predicates. Then use std::upper_bound for each entry. Should give you the position in the list of predicates directly after the matching predicate, if any exists. Only worth it with a considerable number of entries to check compared to predicates

@Ahmed AEK - There are only two vectors: one containing the predicates in the order in which to sort the elements of the other. The number of predicates and lines to write to file vary, hence the use of vectors as opposed to compile-time alternatives. Not knowing what goes on under the hood, I'm only guessing that the more of both there are, the cheaper the 2nd approach gets.

@Erendil "There are only two vectors: one containing the predicates in the order in which to sort the elements of the other" - That doesn't sound at all what your code is doing. Are you sure you've understood what sorting is about?

I think you need to show us some realistic input data and predicates and show us the output. A [mre] would be perfect.

@user17732522 - I guess I should specify that no two preds are identical. Usingstart_with(pred)' , whichever elements in vec` may match during one loop cannot match on subsequent loops.

@Erendil These kinds of constraints are important when evaluating best- and worst-case costs of an algorithm. But there is still more important information missing: Does every element of vec also match at least one of the pred elements? Are both vectors large or does one tend to be significantly smaller than the other? If they are of similar order of size, what is the size ration between the two? How long are the strings in both vectors? To also make a statement about average or typical cost, you need to describe the distribution of inputs as well.

@Ted Lyngmo - The sort order is given by preds. Loop 1: write any line that starts with 'pred1'. Loop 2: write any lines that start with 'pred2', etc

@user17732522 - I see. Well, in my use case, all predicates (usually 2-5) match against at least 3 vec entries (up to 7), but I was thinking  of using whichever approach would come on top for cases where there may be no match...

@Erendil OK, so the number of items is actually small. The current answer and probably most readers would assume that the vectors are very large, because usually that is the situation in which algorithmic optimization is worthwhile. For small input sizes it is not so much the algorithm, but often details such as efficient cache use, optimization-friendliness of the code, etc. which are important for performance.

Also, for these small sizes, it is not unlikely that the file << it << '\n'; output will take most of the time. Have you actually measured what fraction of the time you are wasting in the string matching rather than the file output?

@user17732522 - Is my question already published, i.e. out of Staging Ground (seeing how it's already answerable)? Also, you guys have given me what I consider a perfectly good answer, so should I still add the missing info to the question?

@Homer512 It is my understanding that new objects are created on every iteration, and that creating and passing string_views is cheaper than creating and passing string references. I know I could very well be wrong, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

A reference is not a new object. When you write your loop header for(auto& …), the reference always points at the current object in the vector directly. Changing it to string_view would instead create a new object by converting the string reference to a new string_view. It would be a very cheap conversion but still no reason to think it's better. A string_view is faster than a string copy but nothing beats a simple reference in terms of performance.

Also, yes, your question is out of the staging grounds. Sorry for all the negative votes that came in because of that. Maybe it should have stayed there until all relevant information was part of the question.

@Erendil Ok, I see what you want. It can be solved with partitioning or sorting. In this case, partitioning may be easier. Example

@Ted Lyngmo Thank you, but your code reads unordered lines from 'data.txt' and cout << them when I'm trying to get unordered lines (from popen()) and write them ordered to 'data.txt'

@Erendil You can open any file and write the records to that instead of writing them to std::cout. Thats beside the point. The point is how to partition and filter to get the output you need (whereever you neef it)

@Ted Lyngmo Well, I was asked to be more specific about my use case (when my question addressed many possible use cases) so I'd expect your example to stick to the stated use case. In all cases, I'm writing whole lines to file, so struct Picture {}; is overkill. That said, while your example introduces an extra iteration over data (,or pics), partitioning data seems (a lot?) cheaper for avoiding iterating over previous matches. I'd +1 if I could :). If I'm not mistaken, I could use my lambda with std::partition to file << it... right there, avoiding the extra iteration, right?

@Erendil I used struct Picture for my own sanity. Let it be lines that you match against if you want. It doesn't affect the algorithm as such. Neither does the way I used it in two steps. Drive it through std::ranges and it will be one run from reading, filtering to writing.

let's say you start with N items and P predicates and they are all uniformly distributed, and each item can only be matched by 1 predicate, and that all items will eventually be matched.
first approach is P iterations on N elements, that does N*P predicate calculations, and also N*P element access.
second approach does the following predicate calculations
N + (N-N/P) + (N-2N/P) .... till 0

to simplify by taking N common and using P as common divisor
N * (P/P + (P - 1)/P + (P - 2)/P ... till 0)

the sum is
N * (P * (P + 1)) / 2 / P = N * (P+1) / 2  ... almost (N * P)/2

so in short you will be doing half the predicate evaluations for a very large number of predicates.
on the other hand you will be wasting time moving elements also (N * P)/2 times, so the total number of vector elements access remains the same, you just evaluate the predicate half the time less for a very large number of predicates, for a small number of predicates the difference may not matter as much (because of the +1), and for 1 predicate you end up doing more work.

Please benchmark both approaches for your use-cases because the above analysis is based on a uniform distribution which is not usually correct for real data.

Thank you for the insightful answer. I've timed both approaches (using std::chrono's hi-res clock), but my speed tests have proven very unreliable on the only device on I have (a Poco smartphone), which I why I'm looking for info on what goes on under the hood. What happens to your formula when the number of predicates is always at least 3x smaller then the number of items?

@Erendil so long as the predicate count is larger than 10 then you should have some speed-up, again the distribution is important

@AhmedAEK See comments on the question. The numbers are actually small.

@Erendil for vec < 10 and P as 2-5 it is not worth it, just use the first approach, i don't think the difference is that significant either way. it only becomes significant for large number of inputs and predicates.

@Ahmed AEK Understood. Thank you.
